# ContentTools.js getting me nowhere

Tags: javascript

I recently came across [ContentTools.js](http://getcontenttools.com/) and i thought that might be nice addition to the site im working on. Going through getting started/tutorials gets me nowhere - script is not working however I look at it.

Copying exact same scripts from author page or running it back from master bin works but implementing to actual website fails.

The only thing that worked for me (on empty html page) was that script loaded editable fields erasing it's content either saved or canceled edit (if that makes and sense to you).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      window.onload = function() {
        var editor;
        editor = ContentTools.EditorApp.get();
        editor.init('.editable', 'data-name');
        editor.bind('save', function(regions) {
          var xhr, payload, name;
          this.busy(true);
          payload = new FormData();
          for (name in regions) {
            if (regions.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
              payload.append(name, regions[name]);
            }
          }

          function onStateChange(ev) {
            if (ev.target.readyState == 4) {
              editor.busy(false);
              if (ev.target.status == '200') {
                new ContentTools.FlashUI('ok');
              } else {
                new ContentTools.FlashUI('no');
              }
            }
          }

          xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onStateChange);
          xhr.open('POST', '/save-my-page');
          xhr.send(payload);
        });
      }).call(this);
```

```html
<link href="http://getcontenttools.com/styles/content-tools.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://getcontenttools.com/scripts/content-tools.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p class="editable" data-name="c1">asd</p>
  <p class="editable" data-name="c2">123</p>
  <p class="editable" data-name="c3">asd123</p>

  <div class="ct-app">
    <div class="ct-widget ct-ignition ct-ignition--ready ct-widget--active">
      <div class="ct-ignition__button ct-ignition__button--edit"></div>
      <div class="ct-ignition__button ct-ignition__button--confirm"></div>
      <div class="ct-ignition__button ct-ignition__button--cancel"></div>
      <div class="ct-ignition__button ct-ignition__button--busy"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Ofc all libraries are loaded and there is no js errors. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you have error in your code, some brackets are not aligned, also you should have one `div` element around your p elements and init editor around it, in this case it will init editor for each p, here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zx4sw47L/

P.S. There is a problem with loading fonts, because of cross-domain issue, but example is working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also starting using getContentTools.
From what I understand you have some errors in your HTML markup and you're missing another js file to init getContentTools

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
          <link href="http://getcontenttools.com/styles/content-tools.css" rel="stylesheet" />
          <script src="http://getcontenttools.com/scripts/content-tools.js"></script>
          <script src="/path/to/editor.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div data-editable data-name="c1">
            <p class="editable">asd</p>
        </div>
        <div data-editable data-name="c2">
            <p class="editable">123</p>
        </div>
        <div data-editable data-name="c3">
            <p class="editable">asd123</p>
        </div>
        <!-- this should be deleted as it is generated by getContentTools -->
        <!--
        <div class="ct-app">
            <div class="ct-widget ct-ignition ct-ignition--ready ct-widget--active">
            <div class="ct-ignition__button ct-ignition__button--edit"></div>
            <div class="ct-ignition__button ct-ignition__button--confirm"></div>
            <div class="ct-ignition__button ct-ignition__button--cancel"></div>
            <div class="ct-ignition__button ct-ignition__button--busy"></div>
        </div>
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The editor.js file should look like this to start

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var editor;

});
```

Hope this helps